# Difference between two types of function declaration in javascript inside a class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been working in `React` and `Redux` for past 2 years but when I was using `inheritance` in javascript, I found the difference between these 2 type of function declaration in javascript.

I've the class `a` and a class `b` which inherits from class `a` and whenever I'm running the following snippet, it logs out

```
bfunc called from class a
afunc called from class b
```

I assume that the syntax `bfunc = function(){` puts the function in `this` and the syntax `afunc() {` puts the function in the prototype of class but I'm not really sure. Can someone please explain this behaviour?

```js
class a {
  afunc() {
    console.log('afunc called from class a');
  }

  bfunc = function() {
    console.log('bfunc called from class a');
  }
}

class b extends a {
  afunc() {
    console.log('afunc called from class b');
  }

  bfunc() {
    console.log('bfunc called from class b');
  }
}

const bObject = new b();
bObject.bfunc();
bObject.afunc();
```

```
bfunc called from class a
afunc called from class b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. If you do `console.log(bObject);` you'll see that it has its own `bfunc` property that contains the function.

Since the prototype is only used when the object doesn't have its own property, this takes precedence even though it was put in by the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar said in his answer, and in details:

Using babel this is what your code's transpiled to: [[Follow the link]](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEbQ3gKGrAZgVwHbABQEoFkVpgB7TCUkAUwDoRSBzHAcjA2xLBBoBNpUAJ1IBbEuCiwWeANxEAvoiIAjDsGgBeAVmAAXAJbl8hYiXKUa9Jq1U6uPavyGjxkGGGlyUixYlBvoZWhqAA9dakxedxM0HWMkUzIKKjoGZjY1ez4BYTF_SWVPBSUUW2x4ohQki1TrFjL1YG5s5zyJGELZYt9q3UCAeWUAK2o9TWhMagB3QPw5ZUGRvVoGucQF4dHdWnY42SA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0).

If you beautified the transpiled version of the code you'll notice that defining a function like:

```
  bfunc = function() {
    //
  }
```

Will a add the function to `this`.
While:

```
  bfunc() {
    //
  }
```

Will be added to the prototype it self:

```
b.prototype.bfunc = function () {
    //do something
};
```

Take a [look here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript) on why calling `bfunc` using `this` will take precedence over `prototype`.